# Multidimensional array, key 0

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array like:

```
 $a = array(array('Hello','abc'), 'd');
 var_dump($a);

    array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'Hello' (length=40)
      'class' => string 'abc' (length=3)
  1 => string 'd' (length=6)

var_dump($a[0]);
 array (size=2)
          'title' => string 'Hello' (length=40)
          'class' => string 'abc' (length=3)
```

Why $a[0] is not empty? Anybody can point this out?

//Edit

I've tested that key 0 with this code:

```
If(empty($a[0]))
{
    // Do A
}
else
{
    // Do B
}
```

Why this return Do B?

Comment: Because the value of index 0 is an array

Answer (score 3):

This array `$a = array(array('Hello','abc'), 'd');` is equivalent to:

```
 $a = array(0 => array(0 => 'Hello', 1 => 'abc'), 1 => 'd');
```

PHP will substitute those keys.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to check key 0 value if it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

Because it refers to not empty array which in your case is `array('Hello','abc')` and according to PHP manual of `empty` function description:
"Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist." it will return `false`.